# Fusion Passenger error while Redmine installation on RHEL 6

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, rhel

Предисловие: есть богатый опыт разработки на php, js, но не на ruby(( но жизнь свела...

Появилась необходимость развернуть на Red Hat 6  всем известную софтину, Redmine. Как оказалось она требует Ruby(написана на Ruby on Rails). После наката Ruby 2.2.3, Gems 2.2.2 и прочих натроек и конфигураций сервера и апача, на 3000 порту получилось пробиться к приложению, но застрял на распозновании ошибки приведенной на скрине. [image: ошибка подгрузки файлов конфигураций]

При попытке гугления не получилось отыскать способ , как можно дебажить данные процессы. Как ее можно устранить или хоть узнать в каких файлах и по каким причинам данная ошибка вылезает. В логах апача дублируется текст с приведенного скрина.

Кто знает, отзовитесь!

Update: Первый пункт решен. Теперь проблема с путями наверное.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите скриншот и положите на его место исходный код проблемной области, как вы предполагаете.

Comment: здесь так не принято (добавлять новые вопросы в существующий). задайте, пожалуйста, **новый** вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, следующий апа не будет, будет новый вопрос. Как ток решу этот апдейт.

Comment: Сделайте чат тоже удобнее для мобилки. Функция есть а печатать катастрофа как не удобно. Как минимум кнопку отправить сделайте как в приложении, для комментов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы редактировали YAML файлы с настройками.
YAML парсер говорит, что в каком-то YAML(расширение .yml) файле есть таб.
Нужно найти этот таб и заменить 2-мя пробелами.

Comment: Этот совет я находил на этом ресурсе в английской ветке, но вот способа отследить в каком файле может это быть, не нашёл. Файлов в трэйсе много, а из них я собственно практически никого не трогал. Пишу практически именно из-за их количества. Пару конфигов переименовывать, и в паре вносил данные.

Comment: @Altenrion я бы, в первую очередь, проверил `config/database.yml` и `config/settings.yml` в корне Редмайна

Comment: @Altenrion, найти файлы `*.yml`, содержащие символ табуляции, можно примерно так: `find /каталог -type f -name \*.yml -exec grep -Pl '\t' {} +`

Comment: @Altenrion, можно сразу и заменить символы табуляции на два пробела: `find /каталог -type f -name \*.yml -exec sed -i 's/\t/  /g' {} +`

Comment: Нашел в файле configuration.yml, перечитав в какой последовательности подключаются yml-ки в configuration.rb. Спасибо откликнувшимся, делаю апдейт основного поста. Новая ошибка с путями / файлами.

Comment: @Altenrion нету пути `/index.html`. Есть путь `/`

Comment: В virtual host  вообще не указаны индексные файлы. Насколько я понимаю апач сам по дефолту его ищет?

Comment: @Altenrion ваш запрос попадает в маршрутизатор приложения, который находится в файле `config/routes.rb`. Первая запись там `root :to => 'welcome#index', :as => 'home'` - говорит, о том, что `GET` запрос по адресу `/` будет направлен экшену `index` контроллера `welcome`

Comment: У меня url заканчивается на "/" . посмотрел трэйс, ввел "examle.ru/login" и появилась форма авторизации redmine.  Как настроить чтоб дэф url что либо выводил. Попробовал на signin, так маршрутизатор заругался, мол дубль в правилах "as".

Comment: @Altenrion я посмотрел исходный код Redmine. Если ничего не менять, то по адресу `example.com` будет отрисована https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb - эта вьюшка. Попробуй сейчас строку `root :to => 'welcome#index', :as => 'home'` заменить на `root :to => 'account#login', :as => 'home'`

Comment: Указал, поменялся трэйс, но на дэф урле по прежнему таже ошибка с index.html. А трэйс : home_path  GET  /  account#login  
signin_path  GET|POST  /login(.:format)  account#login. Указыване гет/пост не повлияло)

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26554/discussion-between-maxopka-and-altenrion).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена) познакомился плотно с Ruby  и redhat 6. Linux это всегда интересно)) всем удачи а Махорке ещё и спасибо)